# Regex- To get string separated with a delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to fetch strings which are separated by comma(,) and need to validate the strings

string: event1,event23,event343

Rule : Each value should have event, first value should be event1 and remaining  values can have 'event[1-9]'

I tried `(^event1)(,event[1-9]+)*`  regex but it is not supporting when a string contains more than three values separated by comma

**Update**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^event1)(,event[1-9]+)*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("event1,event112,event39");
```

> Working for : event1,event2
>
> Not working : event1,event2,event3

**Update 2**

Tried my regex at https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

```
Results
.matches() method: false
.lookingAt() method: true
```

Comment: Are you sure the number cannot have a `0`? Try replacing `[1-9]` with `[0-9]`. If you are using it in `matches()`, you may remove `^`. Else, add `$` at the end.

Comment: `boolean check = string.matches("event1(,event[1-9]+)*");`

Comment: You have not posted the code you're using. Just a regex and its certainly not clear that the problem is in the regex. See: How to create a [mcve]. You also need to post an example of a string that you want to match, but doesn't match.

Comment: Usual I read regex from a excel sheet,@ycf_l  @WiktorStribiżew tried ur suggestion but it couldnt help.

Comment: You still don't show a [mcve] - you haven't shown where you are doing the actual matching. However if you add `System.out.println(matcher.matches());` after your code, it prints `true` for `event1,event2,event3` - so it's working for 3 events. There must be something else wrong. The only reason it goes wrong for `event1,event10,event39` is what @WiktorStribiżew said - you didn't include the zero in your character class.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt edited my question with updates

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of case, I split the text into a head and a tail, and repeat:

```
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(event[0-9]+)(?:,(.*))?", 0);
    Matcher m = re.matcher(text);
    while (m.matches()) {
        String head = m.group(1);
        String tail = m.group(2);
        System.out.println(head);
        if (tail == null) {
            break;
        }
        m = re.matcher(tail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate your rule

> Rule : Each value should have event, first value should be event1 and remaining values can have 'event[1-9]'

to a method and use the string methods `startsWith`, `split` and `matches` which i find more readable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "event1,event2,event23";
    System.out.println(validate(str));
}
public static boolean validate (String str){
    return str.startsWith("event1") && Stream.of(str.split(",")).allMatch(e->e.matches("event\\d+"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simply way is to use this regular expression:

```
^event1(,event[1-9])*$
```